# VB - How can I loop a query using a datagrid and return those results the the grid?

Tags: sql, vb.net, foreach

I'm populating a data grid with a .csv file, and I seem to have that working correctly.

What I'm wanting to do now, is on a button click, run a for each loop that basically runs a query against a database and returns the quantity of matching records.

To do so, I need to reference several columns inside the datagrid.

So as an example; for each row in the data grid, I would want to run a select statement that gets the count of results returned where Value1 = Row1, Value2 = Row2, etc.

Comment: Is the datagridview's datasource bound to something or did you just add rows manually?

Comment: Can you specify the type of control you're referring to: System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid, System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid, System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGrid or something else. What flavour of Database?

Comment: This looks like `N+1 Select` problem. You should use join instead of iterating each row and retrieving count of each row.

Comment: The control is a System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView;

How would I join the DataGrid to a SQL query; if they don't exist in the database?

Database is MSSQL

Comment: Are you just trying to iterate the datagridview's rows and use each row's values in a sql query?